# Allow stored procedure to accept the values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I new to SQL, and I need one parameter called `@User1` in the stored procedure to accept just 3 words for example ('max', 'low', 'high'), otherwise it should be an error.

I try to type this but it doesn't work I mean it accept any string value of data and I need to just 3 words:

```
IF @User1 <> 'max' OR @User1 <> 'low' OR @User1 <> 'high'
BEGIN
    SET @ErrorNumber = 3
    RETURN 0 
END
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on *doesn't work*? Is it throwing an error?

Comment: Also what database are you using? Mysql, SQL Server and Postgres are all different products.

Comment: I mean it accept any string value of data and I need to just 3 words to allow @Zakaria

Comment: I use SQL server

Comment: maybe that `ELSE IF` isn't even reached. Check your conditions that come before it.

Comment: @Zakaria yes thanks I check it and it works fine now but I also need to allow case sensitive which function should I use and where to put it ?

Comment: You THROW errors and you should provide a useful error message that the caller of the procedure can understand. By convention a stored procedure returns 0 for success and a non-zero value for error. Bad habits are difficult to break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `AND` instead of an `OR` between your conditions. As from OP's last comment, to also make it case insensitive:

```
IF  LOWER(@User1) <> 'max' and LOWER(@User1) <> 'low' and LOWER(@User1) <>'high'
BEGIN 
    SET @ErrorNumber = 3
    RETURN 0 
END
```

Or simply

```
IF  LOWER(@User1) NOT IN ('max', 'low', 'high')
BEGIN 
    SET @ErrorNumber = 3
    RETURN 0 
END
```

Comment: now all value get error also the max,low and high

Comment: @ahmadnizar you need an `and` instead of an `or` between the conditions. Try again my edited answer!

Comment: It works after I use and  instead of an or, thanks Zakaria

Comment: @ahmadnizar no problem buddy, have a nice day ^^

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to create a stored procedure that accepts one parameter and you want to check that the parameter is in [max, low, high].

Check this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UserSize @User1 nvarchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
    IF  @User1<>'max'  or @User1<>'low' or @User1<>'high'
    BEGIN
          THROW 51000, 'The record does not exist.', 1;  
    END

//do something here

END
GO;
```

Does this work for you?